# Cakephp redirect 301 from old urls with query

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to redirect old URL such as http://www.mysite.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1, to cakephp2 /about. 
my .htaccess has a mod_rewrite deceleration at the top.
I've tried several options in the .htaccess such as:

```
 RewriteRule ^/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1  http://www.mysite.com/about     [R=301,L]
```

What is the correct syntax?
Does it matter which .htaccess I'm using, whether its the one in the top level or the one in app/webroot.
Thanks
Orly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RewriteRule` isn't correct since leading `/` is not matched in `.htaccess` and query string is also not matched.

You can use following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)option=com_content&view=article&id=1(&|$)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.mysite.com/about? [R=301,L]
```

`QUERY_STRING` is carried over to new URL automatically so new URL will become: `http://www.mysite.com/about?option=com_content&view=article&id=1`

Comment: I've added those line, this is the new URL that I'm getting:http://www.mysite.com/about?/about&/about&/about&
and it goes on and on with the /about&/

Comment: Sorry I had missing `?` in the target URL. Check the edit now.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your server has pointing to your web root, you want to add your rules in the **.htaccess** file in that directory. CakePHP’s `RewriteRule` is pretty greedy, so you want to either add your `RewriteRule`s above CakePHP’s; or add `Redirect 301` rules to the bottom of your **.htaccess** file. I tend to favour separating my `RewriteRule`s from my `Redirect`s in this fashion.